# Elastic Beanstalk Autoscaling Group Lifecycle Hooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lifecycle

I would like to add lifecycle hooks to my Elastic Beanstalk's autoscaling group. I see how lifecycle hooks can be added to an autoscaling group through cloudformation, but I don't know how this can be done through Elastic Beanstalk.

To create a lifecycle hook on an autoscaling group, you need the autoscaling group's name. This doesn't appear to be possible since the Elastic Beanstalk resource doesn't have an export for the ASG name.

```
Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LifecycleHook
Properties: 
  AutoScalingGroupName: String
  DefaultResult: String
  HeartbeatTimeout: Integer
  LifecycleHookName: String
  LifecycleTransition: String
  NotificationMetadata: String
  NotificationTargetARN: String
  RoleARN: String
```

The Elastic Beanstalk doesn't allow defining this configuration either. It does allow defining an sns topic, but adding one doesn't appear to change the configuration in the console, and scaling operations don't appear to be using this topic.

```
    - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics
      OptionName: NotificationTopicARN
      Value: !ImportValue MyLifecycleHookTopic
```

How can I add Lifecycle hooks to my Elastic Beanstalk application, so that terminating an environment can go through my graceful shutdown process?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `.ebextensions` files to further modify settings like these.

```
Resources:
  lifecyclehook:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LifecycleHook
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName: { "Ref" : "AWSEBAutoScalingGroup" }
      LifecycleHookName: "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATING"
```

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-elastic-beanstalk-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/environment-resources.md