# Very slow first load time on calls to AWS Elastic Beanstalk server in VPC behind ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I have an Elastic Beanstalk server behind an Application Load Balancer, all inside a VPC. The first call to the server after leaving it along for a while takes a very long time. It's almost as if the instance is being booted up right then! Instead of being already on...

This issue does not present locally, nor outside of a VPC, it only happens in the VPC on AWS so something in my configuration must be off.

The VPC has 3 public and 3 private subnets, in the same availability zones, and the public subnets all have auto-assign public IP on

[image: subnets]
[image: availability zones]
[image: auto assign public ips]

I've assigned these to the network settings on my Elastic Beanstalk environment, assigning the public subnets to the public load balancer, and then the private subnets to the private instance.

[image: load balancer settings]
[image: instance settings]

I've set the auto scaling load balanced group with minimum of 3 instances, and confirmed they're running

[image: auto scaling group]
[image: instances]
[image: status]

Despite this, after leaving the site alone for a while... the first new call to the server consistently takes over one minute, and then works great. I assume I'm just missing something small but cannot figure out what it is...

Thanks in advance!

I am convinced this is not an application issue because, on first load the call takes over one minute, but on subsequent loads it's near instant, and this behavior is constant across days. Locally, I never have this issue. Outside a VPC, I never have this issue.

first/slow load (after leaving the app alone overnight)
[image: slow load]

second/fast load (refreshing right after the above)
[image: fast load]

**UPDATE**

AWS support suggested I deassociate the subnets from my route tables. I did that and now all subnets public and private are showing current routing table Main. Now though, instead of taking a long time all calls to my server are failing!

I tried attaching the internet gateway in that VPC to the routing table via edge association but I'm getting the error that

> Route table contains unsupported route destination. The unsupported route destination is less specific than or non-overlapping with VPC local CIDR

There is one public subnet with overlapping CIDRs with the internet gateway (10.1.0.0/24 on the subnet and 10.1.0.0/24 on the gateway). I tried manually associating that to the Main routing table but still get the same error

Comment: Are you sure its not something related to your web app? E.g. your app has to establish or call external API, DBs connection or some other resource that may take long time to initially start?

Comment: @Marcin Yes I am sure, unfortunately. Same call works near instantly if I just refresh the page after the first load. Adding screenshots to my original question

Comment: Does this happen if you use EB sample app? All the VPC, subnets and the rest stay same, but you just change the deployment app to the sample provided by AWS. This would allow to determine if the issue is general in nature, maybe related to VPC setup, or specific only to your application.

Comment: Also can you post details of your VPC, subnet and route tables setup, NAT and IGW? Screenshot could be used.

Comment: If you go to your ALB screen and check the Monitoring tab, what do you see on "Average Latency" and "Healthy Host" just before you perform your first call? Also, were you able to identify how long you have to wait until the behaviour goes back to your "initial" call?

Comment: Also, can you please share your configuration from "Elastic Beanstalk console" > "Configuration" > "Load balancer"? Looking specially to your "Health check path" (and if that matches a correct path on your application), but other information is useful as well.

Comment: Could you check that this is actually not a DNS issue with your OS/client? Is another tool like wget performing the same? Is nslookup returning a non-cached response fast?

Comment: @JoshuaOhana are you still looking for answers?

Comment: I wonder, if you just put three text files like hello world in index.html , and try to access it through the ALB , does the same issue persist? (or install apache to server some static files, just to test). The test will only take 5 minutes anyway. Worth a shot.

Comment: are you using Aurora as your database? what are the settings of your database?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and checked with the sample application as well! Would be great to learn what was the solution

Comment: I have the same issue, but only happens when I using `xxx.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` domain, after I attach Cloudflare to it,  it became faster.

Answer (score 0):

I this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188826/elastic-beanstalk-autoscaling-group-lifecycle-hooks) what a similar question. Assuming you are using Auto-Scaling most likely you will want to add a LifeCycle hook. You can do that in `ElasticBeanstalk` as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html), by editing the `.ebextensions/as-hook.config` file. You will use the `EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING` transition. In your hook make a request similar to what your application does which can ensure that the instance is ready to start serving traffic.

If you still have issues you could use more techniques for debugging such as `X-Ray` but you would need to then run the Agent and configure the sdk for your app which would be a bit of work so it may not be worth the effort. If it is simply the first request which takes a long time hooks will be the way to go.